# How to change color for other players that joined?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have tank model. I colored this model in Unity with materials.
So, how to change materials color, if it's second player model, for example?

[image]

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of different ways to do this depending on your situation.

**1.** If you are only allowing a maximum of 2 or 4 players, then you could create different tank prefabs (with different color materials) for each player, and then instantiate the corresponding tank for each player when they join the game. This is the simplest solution, and would be a fine way to solve this problem.

**2.** If you want to change the color of the tanks without creating more materials or prefabs, then you could use Material Property Blocks to change the color of each material on the new players tanks at runtime. Check out [this question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/411601/change-the-color-of-a-material-for-only-one-object.html) and [this article](http://thomasmountainborn.com/2016/05/25/materialpropertyblocks/) for more info. Using the Material Property Block solution from that article requires creating a copy of a built-in shader and editing it, but you only need to add one line of code. If you haven't worked with shaders before then they might look intimidating but it's not too bad.

Since you would be supplying the colors at runtime, you could either use global Color fields on your script for each player tanks materials, or you could generate the color hue using the player index (recommended - example below). Using the player index (`playerIndex` = 1, 2...`maxPlayers`) would allow you to have any number of different tank types, and you can use the following code to get the color (which you would then supply to the Material Property Block's color property).

```
var c = Color.HSVToRGB(startHue + (playerIndex / (float)maxPlayers), 1, 1);
```

For more info about generating colors like this, check out the documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.HSVToRGB.html). You can pick a `startHue` (which will be the color for player 1) using the hue value from the HSL color picker [here](http://colorizer.org/).